# how to use arrays splice method in ion-list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list of data that populates an ionic list with delete function when we swipe the list to left.

I am able to make the delete function to work, however i am stuck how to splice the list when the response if true.

I am using `$scope.data.splice($index, 1);`

this is my code

**HTML**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="x in data track by $index" href="#/item/{{x.mif_no}}" class="item-remove-animate">
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive icon ion-trash-a" on-touch="Delete(x.mif_no,x.item_no)"></ion-option-button>
</ion-item>
```

and this is the js code

**JS**

```
$scope.Delete = function(docno,itemno){
$http({
  method: "post",
  url: apiServer + "/fg-in-del.php",
  data: {
    mifno: docno,
    itemno: itemno,
    Dbserver: window.localStorage.getItem("server"),
    Dbuser: window.localStorage.getItem("username"),
    Dbpass: window.localStorage.getItem("password"),
    Dbname: window.localStorage.getItem("dbname"),
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  $scope.data=response.data;
  if (response.data == 1){
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Delete',
      template: 'Data has been deleted.'
    });
    $scope.data.splice($index, 1);
  }else {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Delete',
      template: 'Failed to delete data.'
    });
    console.log(response.data);
  }
}, function(response) {
  $scope.data=response.data;
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Delete',
    template: 'Failed to delete data.'
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS

```
 $scope.Delete = function(docno,itemno,index){
      $http({
        method: "post",
        url: apiServer + "/fg-in-del.php",
        data: {
          mifno: docno,
          itemno: itemno,
          Dbserver: window.localStorage.getItem("server"),
          Dbuser: window.localStorage.getItem("username"),
          Dbpass: window.localStorage.getItem("password"),
          Dbname: window.localStorage.getItem("dbname"),
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        if (response.data == 1){
          var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Delete',
            template: 'Data has been deleted.'
          });
          $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
        }else {
          var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Delete',
            template: 'Failed to delete data.'
          });
          console.log(response.data);
        }
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.data=response.data;
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Delete',
          template: 'Failed to delete data.'
        });
      });
    }
```

HTML

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="x in data track by $index" ng-hide="x.deleted" href="#/item/{{x.mif_no}}" class="item-remove-animate">
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive icon ion-trash-a" on-touch="Delete(x.mif_no,x.item_no, $index); x.deleted = true;"></ion-option-button>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: its working now, but why at the index that swiped and deleted, the list still shown and swiped (of course with new data in the list) instead return to it normal list view?

Comment: you mean the list is not getting refreshed after you delete an item?

Comment: The list get refreshed but the delete button from the previous deleted list still shown(not hidden). I have manually to swipe it back to hide the menu.

Comment: still the same, the list get refreshed but the delete button is still shown in the  list index that we clicked just now.

Comment: weird it must be something else that doesnt have to do with the splice, since the item gets deleted.

Comment: could be a bug from ionic?

Comment: no i dont think so, must be something with the html, try to post more code maybe or make a new question

Comment: ok, will ask a new questions for this issue in this new [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713736/splice-method-in-ion-list-list-get-refreshed-but-the-delete-button-still-shown)

Answer (score 0):

this code will never work because:

if you set

```
$scope.data=response.data;
```

and then check

```
if (response.data == 1){
```

`$scope.data` has to be `1` inside this if condition.

It isn't possible to splice `1`? and therefore

```
$scope.data.splice($index, 1);
```

won't work.

Comment: the response from the api server will be 1 if successful delete the data, therefor i want to remove it from the list if the server response is 1, else it won't do anything simply will give an alert that failed to delete the data.